# How to delete one file from a folder, if two files with the same name and different ending exist in the same folder?

Tags: python

I am struggling to figure how to remove file from one folder based on a `if` condition. Also I have muddled myself into making the `if` statement too..

**Here is the folders:**

```
Desktop\Signed\
Desktop\to sign\
```

**Files inside the folders above:**

```
   Desktop\Signed\
Document 1 User1.docx
Document 1 User2.docx

  Desktop\to sign\
Document 2.docx
```

I have an application that does the following:

- Both users need to sign the `Document 2.docx`. I have multiple users, in this scenario I will use `User1` & `User2`
- Soon as one User has hit save, a file is created in `Signed` folder naming as: `Document 2 User1.docx`
- Soon as it is saved this what the tree line looks like now:

  ```
    Desktop\Signed\
  Document 1 User1.docx
  Document 1 User2.docx
  Document 2 User1.docx # New file

   Desktop\to sign\
  Document 2.docx
  ```
- As soon as the other user signs it and hits save, tree line changes to this:

  ```
    Desktop\Signed\
  Document 1 User1.docx
  Document 1 User2.docx
  Document 2 User1.docx # Previous New file
  Document 2 User2.docx # New file create

   Desktop\to sign\
  #File removed becasue there are minimum of two files with same name and both users have signed it
  ```

**Here is the actual code that does the work behind the scenes of deleting the files:**

```
    #Usernames to verify 2 word documents exist
    User1 = (signed+ os.path.basename(self.p).strip('.docx') +' User1'+ '.docx')
    User2 = (signed + os.path.basename(self.p).strip('.docx') +' User2'+ '.docx')
```

....

```
    if os.path.exists(User1) and os.path.exists(User2) or os.path.exists(User3) or os.path.exists(user4):
        os.remove(to_sign + os.path.basename(self.p)) # Remove the to sign file if two users have signed it
        Print("Both signed")
    else:
        print("One signed")
```

This works as it should, but here is my actual problem.

If one of the users is signing the document, as an example `User1`.

Soon as he hits save, the document is created in signed folder and the `to sign`folder remains the same.

BUT... if he accidentally presses save again, the file from `to sign` deletes.

This is because the if statement sees `User1` file already exists and just deletes it. Now the fact it is deleted, I need to open the signed document, clear everything out and save it back into `to sign`folder for the other user to sign, because I need minimum of two people signing it.

How can I avoid this?

This what I came up with:

Create an `if` statement to do the following: Check if folder `signed` has two files named the same but has a different ending string to it

Comment: The logical result of your if statement is ambiguous. Should `if False and False or True or False` evaluate to `True` or `False`? As written, it evaluates to `True`. You should add parentheses to clearly show (and control) the operator precedence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add `== True` end of if your statement, but separating multiple users into pairs coding them into elif statements.

```
   if os.path.exists(User1) and os.path.exists(User2) == True:
        os.remove(to_sign + os.path.basename(self.p)) # Remove the to sign file if two users have signed it
        Print("Both signed")
    elif ...: #add more users
    else:
        print("One signed")
```

or as [S3DEV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6340496/s3dev) & [Cubic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938694/cubic) suggested:

you can simply drop `== True` and have it the following way:

```
   if os.path.exists(User1) and os.path.exists(User2):
```

Comment: True is implied.  You can drop '== True' altogether.

Comment: Why would you drop the `== True` our of curiosity ?

Comment: @98Ed because something either is true or not true. True == True is the same as True. False == True is the same as False. So you're just writing the same thing in a longer way (similarly, writing `x == False` is just a longer way of writing `not x`).

Comment: For a nonlogical example, it'd be like insisting to write `+ 0` after every number - you can't just write x + 5, you have to write `((x + 0) + (5 + 0)) + 0`, otherwise it just doesn't feel number-y enough...